# SQL duplicate row Inner join

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have 2 tables  grades table and groups table. i want to show all the grades and student id from a group but it returns duplicate rows.

Here is my Code:

```
select * from grades Inner join groups On groups.group_ID = grades.group_id where grades.professor_ID = '1-1200102'
```

[image: And here is my output]

Comment: show your expected output? Because the result set you showed has two rows for -027-013 Student_ID and ID is different

Comment: Do you want to show all grades for all students in single group identified by ID number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your grades.id and grades.student_ID are different. Use `GROUP_BY student_ID` for distinct records according to student_ID

Comment: Thanks for the idea btw. I also found a work around.

    select * from grades inner join groups on groups.group_id = grades.group_id WHERE grades.professor_ID = '1-1200102' AND groups.ID = grades.student_ID

Comment: Glad that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked.

```
select * from grades inner join groups on groups.group_id = grades.group_id WHERE grades.professor_ID = '1-1200102' AND groups.ID = grades.student_ID
```